# C# webjob convert.todouble works wrong on azure

Tags: c#, azure, type-conversion

i've got a problem with my azure webjob. Locally in console it works as it should, but after uploading it to azure something happens.
I've a string 1.0001 and locally in console it converts as it should, but on azure it forgets about dot and the result it 10001. What can cause problem like this? Everything else works well.
I am using Convert.ToDouble

Comment: I don't suppose you have a [mcve]?

Comment: Can you share the code which is having this issue? are you sure that some thing else in the application is not causing this issue?

Comment: Running with the same CultureInfo?

Comment: Please share more details, codes and the webjob logs. I test webjob with Convert.ToDouble , it worked well. You could check my [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAix6.png).

Comment: Hello, I don't know what caused this issue. I solved it converting string to float and then to double. It worked fine for me

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears because the system where the code runs has a different culture than what you are using in your development environment.

I normally replace the commas with dots and use `decimal.Parse`:

`decimal.Parse(yourString.Replace(',', '.'), NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`